# How can I implement something similar to `value_counts()` in a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I had the following data

```
Orchard    Tree
1           Apple
2           Peach
1           Peach
3           Apple
```

How could I group by `orchard` and show how many times each tree occurs in the orchard?  The result would look like

```
Tree     Apple  Peach
Orchard
1          1     1
2          0     1
3          1     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) what you want?

```
In [48]: df
Out[48]:
   Orchard   Tree
0        1  Apple
1        2  Peach
2        1  Peach
3        3  Apple

In [49]: df.pivot_table(index='Orchard', columns='Tree', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
Out[49]:
Tree     Apple  Peach
Orchard
1            1      1
2            0      1
3            1      0
```

or using `groupby()` and `unstack()` (that's how `pivot_table()` does it under the hood):

```
In [57]: df.groupby(['Orchard','Tree']).size().unstack('Tree', fill_value=0)
Out[57]:
Tree     Apple  Peach
Orchard
1            1      1
2            0      1
3            1      0
```

Comment: Yea, perfect.   Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let's not forget good ol' `value_counts`
Just have to make sure to reduce to `Tree` after the `groupby`

```
df.groupby('Orchard').Tree.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

Comment: cool, i didn't know that `unstack()` function has `fill_value` parameter

Comment: Ah, I tried something like this, but didn't do the `unstack` part.  This is good to know, thanks.